# IQueryableget distinct results by an objects property

Tags: c#, linq

I have this query:

```cs
from snd in _context.SenderPhones
where snd.ApplicationUserId == applicationUser.Id & !snd.IsDeleted  
select new
{
    SenderPhoneId = snd.SenderPhoneId,
    Phone = snd.Phone
}
```

I need to find a way not to include duplicate phones. The query has to be IQuerable and not enumerable.
Whats the best and most simple way to achieve so.

Comment: [Distinct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.distinct?view=net-5.0)?

Answer (score 1):

Normally to get remove duplicates you would use [Queryable.Distinct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.distinct?view=net-5.0)

**The solution to your problem depends on what you define as "duplicate phone".**

If `SenderPhoneId` is the primary key, then you can't have two phones with the same SenderPhoneId. So if the primary key is part of your definition of "duplicate phone", then you can't have duplicate phones.

Because of your question, I assume that `SenderPhoneId` is not the primary key, and that two phones with different primary key may have the same value for property SenderPhoneId.

So you can have telephones like:

```
Id    SenderPhoneId     Phone     ApplicationUserId    IsDeleted     Name
 3         5             xxx             10               false     "John"    
 4         5             xxx             10               false     "John"
 5         5             xxx             10               false     "Mary"
```

These three phones have a different Id. There is no duplicate phone. However, If you select only `SenderPhoneId` and `Phone`, you would have:

```
 SenderPhoneId     Phone
      5             xxx        (was phone 3)
      5             xxx        (was phone 4)         
      5             xxx        (was phone 5)
```

Do you define these phones as the same phone? If so, just put your distinct at the end:

```
int applicationUserId = ...
var uniqueSenderPhones = dbContext.SenderPhones
    .Where(senderPhone => senderPhone.ApplicationUserId == applicationUserId
                       && !senderPhone.IsDeleted)
    .Select(senderPhone => new
    {
        SenderPhoneId = senderPhone.SenderPhoneId,
        Phone = senderPhone.Phone,
    })
    .Distinct();
```

This example would leave only one phone:

```
SenderPhoneId      Phone
    5               xxx
```

But if you say: "No, these three phones are not the same phone, some of them had a different Name, even though I didn't select this property", then you would first have to select the properties that make a phone unique, then do the Distinct, and finally select the properties that you want:

```
var uniqueSenderPhones = dbContext.SenderPhones
    .Where(senderPhone => senderPhone.ApplicationUserId == applicationUserId
                       && !senderPhone.IsDeleted)
    .Select(senderPhone => new
    {
        Name = senderPhone.Name,
        SenderPhoneId = senderPhone.SenderPhoneId,
        Phone = senderPhone.Phone,
    })
    .Distinct()
    .Select(senderPhone => new
    {
        SenderPhoneId = senderPhone.SenderPhoneId,
        Phone = senderPhone.Phone,
    });
```

In this example you would get:

```
 SenderPhoneId     Phone
      5             xxx        (was phone 3 or 4)
      5             xxx        (was phone 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GroupBy() in combination with First() like so:

```
_context.SenderPhones
        .Where(senderPhone => senderPhone.ApplicationUserId == applicationUser.Id &&
                              !senderPhone .IsDeleted)
        .GroupBy(senderPhone => senderPhone.SenderPhoneId)
        .Select(sernderPhones => senderPhones.First())
        .Select(senderPhone => new 
                          { 
                              SenderPhoneId = senderPhone.SenderPhoneId,
                              Phone = senderPhone.Phone 
                          });
```

This should return a list of SenderPhones with unique ids by always just taking the first one if multiple SenderPhones with the same id exist (if you wanted them to be unique by SenderPhone.Phone.Id then just replace the property used in GroupBy).

If you want to make sure that always the same sender phone is taken if multiple with the same id exist then add an `OrderBy()` with an appropriate sorting condition before `First()`.